# htaccess RewriteEngine to be declared twice

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to apply a redirect on a certain webpage using its htaccess.

My question is - since the htaccess file had already declared a RewriteEngine on for forcing HTTPS that goes something like the snippet below:

```
#Forcing HTTPS

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

#End Forcing HTTPS
```

Do I need to put another RewriteEngine on for my redirects?

Would it be alright if I declare my redirects inside this code block?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, but the simple way to test that is to add the new code and see if it works

Comment: Think of it this way: `RewriteEngine on` does not actually "declare" a RewriteEngine, it merely switches it on. That means you do not actually declare it twice at all. And as with every switch: switching something on multiple times does not really break it. Even if it has already been switched on ...

Comment: How did you get on with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72665826/369434) below?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive. If you are coding this yourself then you should not repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. (Repetition of the `RewriteEngine On` directive generally comes about through scripts auto-maintaining the `.htaccess` file or code being blindly copy/pasted.)

It's logical (and more readable) to have the `RewriteEngine` directive once at the top of the file, before any mod_rewrite directives. However, its location in the file does not strictly matter from a technical point of view.

If you do repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive multiple times throughout the file then it's actually the last instance of that directive that "wins" and controls the entire file. The earlier `RewriteEngine` directives are effectively ignored/overridden. So, having multiple `RewriteEngine` directives is actually quite misleading.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
: Some directives...

RewriteEngine On
: Some more directives...

RewriteEngine Off
```

The net result of the above is that the `RewriteEngine` is `Off` for the entire file and *none* of the mod_rewrite directives are processed in the whole file (context).

This allows you to quickly "comment out" (disable) all the mod_rewrite directives in the file with a single `RewriteEngine Off` directive at the very end of the file. As noted in [the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine), "Use this directive to disable rules in a particular context, rather than commenting out all the RewriteRule directives."

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine

---

*Aside:* The same principle applies to the `RewriteBase` directive.